# Calculating Transfer Functions From Harmonic Distortion Percentage

Tags: transfer-function, measurement, distortion

Hi I am working on emulating a piece of analog audio equipment and would like to be able to create a transfer function based on the measured percentages of harmonic distortion.

I know that harmonic distortion can be modeled as follows (assuming range of -1 to 1):

2nd order: y = x - (1/2) * (x^2 * sign)

3rd order: y = x - (1/3) * x^3

The amount of distortion can then be changed by mixing wet and dry signals, and frequency response approximated by filtering the polynomial input.

What I want to know is how to calculate a wet dry mix based on harmonic distortion percentage, and how that applies to these transfer functions. Is there an equation / method I can use to calculate this?